# Gsub a string only if string has value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string

Here's my code:

```
<a href="<%= foo_path(foo) %>" class="<%= foo.roles.empty? ? foo.roles.gsub(',', ' ') : ""  %>">

undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

I just want to output a gsub of a string if there is something inside `roles`, if not, then just spit out an empty string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if your `empty?` didn't blow up on nil, you've got the then and else paths of your ternary reversed.

Comment: Ahh logic in a view! Put it in a presenter or helper.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Where would I put the helper? Can you write a small example (since this *is* a simple use case) as an answer?

Comment: @Serg Perhaps `app/helpers/foo_helper.rb`. In general it’s best to have as little going on in a view as possible—it should just extract values from objects, manipulating them isn’t its job. Personally I prefer presenters to helpers, though (search for “presenter pattern” & “decorator pattern”).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I think it's not so bad to have _presentation_ logic in a view, as the view is there to handle _presentation_ and the controller (or model) to handle _business_ logic (primarily). That said, I agree it would be better in a helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil.to_s` => `''`, and your substitution has no effect on an empty string, so you can completely skip the `empty?` test like so:

```
<a href="<%= foo_path(foo) %>" class="<%= foo.roles.to_s.gsub(',', ' ')  %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `blank?` [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)

```
<a href="<%= foo_path(foo) %>" class="<%= foo.roles.blank? ? "" : foo.roles.gsub(',', ' ')  %>">
```